# Error : Expected a qualified name after 'typename' C++

Tags: c++

Im new to c++ and its developing i have used Templetes there where i use 
typename and templete i got error which says `Expected a qualified name after 'typename'`

please find my code below. and I would be very grateful if anyone could point out my stupidity. Thanks

```
class LapIplImage{
private:
    IplImage *m_img;

public:
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  construct
    LapIplImage():m_img(NULL){}
    LapIplImage  <typename type>(int width, int height):m_img(0){ Create(width, height); }
    ~LapIplImage(){ Release(); }

//Expected a qualified name after 'typename'
```

Comment: should not this be like this
 <typename type> LapIplImage (int width, int height):m_img(0){ Create(width, height); }
    ~LapIplImage(){ Release(); } Also where are you using type ?

Comment: change <typename type> to <typename T>

Comment: and also you do not use it in any way so I don't see any point why you need template here

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the word "template":
1.

```
class LapIplImage{
private:
    IplImage* m_img;

public:
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  construct
    LapIplImage():m_img(nullptr){}
    template <typename type> LapIplImage (int width, int height):m_img(0){ Create(width, height); }
    ~LapIplImage(){ Release();}
};
```

Comment: This helped me find a typo, watch out for "tempalte"! :)

Answer (score -1):

You can not use name that is used as identifier.

So you can try some word that is not used by system .

Like typ or TypE .

Comment: `type` is a valid identifier in C++, not a keyword.